# typeof(System.Net.WebUtility).GetMethod returns `null` for .NetStandard2 (works fine with .NetFramework4.6.1)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How to write code below in **.NetStandard2** so it won't return `null`?

> *It works fine with .NetFramework4.6.1*

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(System.Net.WebUtility).GetMethod(nameof(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode),
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new[]
        {
            typeof(byte[]),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(int)
        },
        null);
```

Looking for [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs#L399) to be exact but that one is for **.NetFramework4.7** and couldn't find `System.Net.WebUtility` source in [CoreFx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src) neither.

Comment: My random guess would be that the parameters are different between .NetStandard and the Framework?

Comment: Please explain why you are down voting!

Comment: @CShark unfortunately couldn't located `System.Net.WebUtility` in [CoreFx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src) but reference has the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is really asking for a method named in `System.Net.WebUtility` named `UrlEncode` that

1. `static`
2. Can be non-`public` (As your link shows, actually `private`)
3. Accepts 3 parameters: `byte[]`, `int`, `int`.

[But `.NET Standard 2.0` doesn't define any such method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netstandard-2.0). So conforming implementations of .NET Standard 2.0 - including .NET Core 2.0 - are free to not implement it. And that is exactly what corefx does. There is no such method in the corefx implementation of System.Net.WebUtilities: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs

Have you considered using [`UrlEncodeToBytes(byte[], int, int)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs#L390) instead? It is present in .NET Standard 2.0 and should be supported in .NET Framework 4.6.1 as well as .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Thank you!  According to https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(Byte(),Int32,Int32) it shouldn't be under `System.Runtime.Extensions`.  I appreciate your help.